# Packer delete cached iso

Tags: vmware, esxi, packer, ovf

I'm using packer for ova files creation.
I'm running it on a nested ESXi.
I couldn't find a way to delete the cached iso, which is stored by default at: `/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/packer_cache/*.iso` (assuming that I'm using datastore1 as my datastore).

Answer (score 0):

Use the vSphere (web) client. Browse to the database, select the file(s) and remove them. See [VMware vSphere 5.1 Documentation Center](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.ICbase/Welcome/welcome.html) for more information.

Comment: Is it part of packer functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

No, Packer will create this folder to store supporting files if `remote_type` is used. One have to remove the folder manually afterwards.